# Console stuck at reading file and filter number of data characters

Tags: c, arrays

I didn't have any error when running the codes below. But on the command console it seems to be stuck on Processing filename xxxxx as below.

May I ask how do I use if condition to filter out number of data characters of less than 50 in line 67, I try to use `strlen(array[count].data) >= 1 && strlen(array[count].data) <= 50` but doesn't seem to work ?

> Enter filename: testdata.txt
>
> Processing filename testdata.txt ...

Sample Source txt file:

```
9001:0002:9003:0021:CLS
0001:0010:0003:0021:CLS
8001:0002:8002:0080:<HTML>
0001:4002:0002:0080:<BODY>
0004:0002:0002:0080:JHJKJBKHJBIUHBKBKHBKHHBKJBKJNKJKHHKUHKJLHBKHBKHBHBHBKHBHBHBHBBHHBHBJKJHKJHKJHKUHIUJ
```

Source code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h>

//struct definition
struct record{
int src;
int dest;
int type;
int port;
char data[100];
};


int main()
{
struct record *array;

FILE* inFile; //file handle or pointer
FILE* outFile;
FILE* errorFile;
char filename[100];

int count = 0;  //keep track of number of records in memory
int i = 0;
int test;
int n1 = 0; //keep track number of correct records
int n2 = 0; //keep track number of error records

array = (struct record *) malloc(sizeof(struct record));

//User to enter filename
printf("Enter filename: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

printf("Processing filename %s ...\n", filename);
inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
if (inFile == NULL) //check if file handler is invalid
{
    printf("Could not open file %s\n", filename);
    exit(1); //error status code
}

test = fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d",
    &array[count].src, &array[count].dest, &array[count].type, &array[count].port);
fgets(array[count].data, 100, inFile);
while (test != EOF){
    count++;
    array = (struct record *) realloc(array, (count + 1)*sizeof(struct record));
    test = fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%s",
        &array[count].src, &array[count].dest, &array[count].type, &array[count].port, &array[count].data);
}
fclose(inFile); //must always close file once done

outFile = fopen("data_1.txt", "wt");
errorFile = fopen("data_error.txt", "wt");
if (outFile == NULL) //check if file handler is invalid
{
    printf("Could not write to file \n", filename);
    exit(1);
}

if (count > 0){
    printf("Viewing all records: ", count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if (array[count].src >= 1 && array[count].src <= 1024 && array[count].dest >= 1 && array[count].dest <= 1024 && array[count].type >= 1 && array[count].type <= 10 && array[count].port >= 1 && array[count].port <= 1024)
            n1++;
            fprintf(outFile, "%d %d %d %d",
            (i + 1),
            array[count].src,
            array[count].dest,
            array[count].type,
            array[count].port
            );
    }
}
else
{
    n2++;
    fprintf(errorFile, "%d %d %d %d",
        (i + 1),
        array[count].src,
        array[count].dest,
        array[count].type,
        array[count].port
        );
}

fclose(errorFile);
fclose(outFile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` returns `int` not `char` , so `test` should be `int` .

Comment: You are missing an `fgets` inside the `while` loop. So likely `test` is going to be continuously `0` and hence the loop will be infinete. May I suggest that you use a debugger to help you find such problems? Or even basic `printf` debug statements. Learning to debug your own code is a useful long term skill.

Comment: @kaylum OP is using `fscanf` and stores its `return` into `test` inside `while` loop , so that wont be problem here I think . And how does `fgets` come here ?

Comment: @ameyCU Have a closer look. The `fscanf` only gets the first 4 columns of the input. The last column of the input is a string and OP is using `fgets` to get that. Not how I would do it but that's the way the code is. BTW, I agree that your pick up regarding `test` type is indeed a bug and needs to be fixed too.

Comment: I change the test to int but got the error as below. I google and confirm that I launch this project as console application. I updated the question with the latest code  -> 1>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open D:\Dropbox\Laptop\School\C++\Project\Debug\Project.exe for writing

Comment: @kaylum `fscanf` inside loop also reads the string with `4` integers , and therefore no need of `fgets` inside loop . OP mixed up things between that .

Comment: @ameyCU OP just changed it :-) The `fscanf` didn't have that last string read when I commented.

Comment: @DoranL Please don't change the code on us like that. It invalidates all the comments. If you must, provide an update below your original code.

Comment: @DoranL See this , this creates confusion , please don't so such things . And even changed data type of `test` .

Comment: Oops, sorry about that ...

Comment: @DoranL Your new error has nothing to do with the code change. It means you probably have a window open somewhere that is running the program so the compiler cannot overwrite the binary.

Comment: Thanks i saw that. the code is working now. Would you be able to advise how could i filter the string length for data ?

Comment: Actually, do you want to keep strings <50 characters, or do you want to throw those away or do you want to store just the first 50 characters? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: For any lines that's < 50 it will be fprintf to outFile. for lines containing >50 characters it will be fprintf to errorFile. The bottom if else statement is not complete yet.

Comment: Then the `strlen` conditions you have shown are fine. If you can't get it to work then you need to explain what the incorrect behaviour is (more than just "it doesn't work"). Probably should start a new question for that as this one has gone south.

Comment: Thanks .. will post it in another question

Comment: @DoranL please indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many common errors in this. Which book are you reading?

```
array = (struct record *) malloc(sizeof(struct record));
test = fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d",
&array[count].src, &array[count].dest, &array[count].type, &array[count].port);
fgets(array[count].data, 100, inFile);
while (test != EOF){
    count++;
    array = (struct record *) realloc(array, (count + 1)*sizeof(struct record));
    test = fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%s", &array[count].src,  &array[count].dest
                                          , &array[count].type, &array[count].port
                                          , &array[count].data);
}
```

Forgive me. I took the liberty to clean up a bit of your code and condense some of the logic.

**[You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)**.

While I'm on the topic of types, isn't your compiler warning you about the type of `&array[count].data` being incompatible with the type that corresponds to `%s`? Don't cast it. Just remove the `&` and recognise how the expression `array[count].data` that denotes an array is converted to a pointer of the appropriate type.

**`x = realloc(x, ...);` where `x` is whatever expression is (almost) always incorrect**. You need to use a temporary variable so you can handle errors correctly without leaking memory (example below)... While I'm on the topic of `realloc` usage, the first argument can be `NULL` and `realloc` will act like `malloc` in that case, so technically that first `malloc` is unnecessary bloat...

```
struct record *array = NULL;
void *temp = realloc(array, (count + 1) * sizeof *array);
if (!temp) {
    puts("ERROR ALLOCATING MEMORY!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
array = temp;
```

**Have you considered the difference between `fgets` and `fscanf("%s", ...)`?** Are you aware that the former is for reading *lines*, while the latter is for reading *words*? This would explain your problem; `fscanf` is halting when it sees a space, leaving everything after the space to be processed by the next `fscanf` call. The result? An infinite loop of `fscanf` fails.

**Have you considered that not all `fscanf` fails return `EOF`?** If you ask `fscanf` to read an `int` (using `%d`) and it immediately encounters non-decimal digits it can't proceed any further; a *conversion failure* occurs.

**If you want to ensure that `fscanf` reads all 5 fields successfully, you need to compare the return value to 5, not to `EOF`.**

I think you most likely meant to read *the remainder of the line* following your four colon-separated `int`s, and here's how I'd naively do that:

```
array = NULL;
struct record record;
while (fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d:%99[^\n]", &record.src,  &record.dest
                                            , &record.type, &record.port
                                            ,  record.data) == 5) {
    /* It's possible that a user might enter more than   *
     * 99 chars for the last field, so when that happens *
     * we should discard the remainder...                */
    if (getchar() != '\n') {
        puts("WARNING: Maximum field length for data is 99; user input truncated");
        fscanf(inFile, "%*[^\n]");
    }

    void *temp = realloc(array, (count + 1) * sizeof *array);
    if (!temp) {
        puts("ERROR ALLOCATING MEMORY!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array = temp;
    array[count++] = record;
}
```